# PHP SQL driver performance

Tags: php, sql-server

Are there any performance benefits in using the newer PDO driver (2.0) PHP driver for SQL Server as opposed to using 1.1? I was wondering if it was worth the time to update the driver and the code.

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlsrvphp.codeplex.com/ mentions a release date of `August 5, 2010`.

> Version 2.0 of the Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server is now available.
>
> Any code that was written to work with the previous releases should work with the current version 2.0 release.

I would assume the upgrade is safe